# Define global variable in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables, jquery-events

I'm not sure if I'm explaining this right, but here it goes ...

I have a function that works in JQuery to assign the selected dropdown value to a variable and then pass the variable to a different part of the HTML when a confirmation button is clicked.

Here's a stripped down version of the HTML

```
<p id="t1"></p> 
<select id="selectLevel">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   <option value="6">6</option>
   <option value="7">7</option>
   <option value="8">8</option>
   <option value="9">9</option>
   <option value="10">10</option>
   <option value="11">11</option>
   <option value="12">12</option>
   <option value="13">13</option>
   <option value="14">14</option>
   <option value="15">15</option>
   <option value="16">16</option>
   <option value="17">17</option>
   <option value="18">18</option>
   <option value="19">19</option>
   <option value="20">20</option>
</select>
<span class="btn" id="confirmLevel">Confirm</span>
```

And here's the JQuery I used.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#confirmLevel').click(function() {
        var PClevel = $("#selectLevel option:selected").text();
        $('#t1').append('Level ' + PClevel); 
    });
});
```

The problem is, if I later try to call the PCLevel variable for other functions, nothing happens. What am I missing here? Or would it be better to skip JQuery altogether and just use Javascript to do the same thing?

Comment: jquery is javascript lib we can say they are the same. can you share all relevant code to question how you declare the global an how you call it on the other function

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that `PClevel` is scoped inside the click handler. It cannot be accessed outside. In order for code outside to see `PClevel`, declare it outside and have the click handler just modify it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var PClevel; // Code inside the ready handler can see it.

    $('#confirmLevel').click(function() {
        PClevel = $("#selectLevel option:selected").text();
        $('#t1').append('Level ' + PClevel); 
    });
});

// or

var PClevel; // Now it's a global. Everyone can see it.
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#confirmLevel').click(function() {
        PClevel = $("#selectLevel option:selected").text();
        $('#t1').append('Level ' + PClevel); 
    });
});
```

Comment: `$('#confirmLevel').click(function() {
        PClevel = $("#selectLevel option:selected").text();
        $('#t1').append('Level ' + PClevel); 
somefunction(PClevel )
    });` this accessible right?

Comment: @guradio *"if I later try to call the PCLevel variable for other functions, nothing happens"* - you missed this part.

Answer (score 1):

Simply declare the variable on the global scope.

```
var PClevel = '';
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#confirmLevel').click(function() {
        PClevel = $("#selectLevel option:selected").text();
        $('#t1').append('Level ' + PClevel); 
    });
});
```

It would be worth reading up on javascript scopes as they are relevant whether you are using jQuery or not.

http://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/

Comment: can we use the global variable inside any function?

Answer (score 0):

Define PClevel as Global Variable `var PClevel;` and update the var on select change so you can access it across different functions.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var PClevel;
  PClevel = $("#selectLevel option:selected").text();
  $('#selectLevel').change(function(){
    PClevel = $("#selectLevel option:selected").text();
  });
  $('#confirmLevel').click(function() {
    $('#t1').append('Level ' + PClevel); 
  });
});
```

Plnkr Example : https://plnkr.co/edit/4KsLTahhq146ttwEcX8E?p=preview

Updated Plnkr with multiple functions

Answer (score 0):

We can use window object, and set the variable on this window object as:

```
window.PClevel = 'value'
```